# First Element of String array printing null

Tags: java, string

First element of string array printing null. Please explain why it is not printing the first element of string array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] array = new String[aa];
    System.out.println("Please enter 20 names to sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = s.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(array[0]);

}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure `aa` is what you think it is?

Comment: Please give an example of *exactly* what input you're giving your code, and how you're running it.  A [mcve] would be even better.

Comment: The code doesn't compile

Comment: Change `String[] array = new String[aa]` to `String[] array = new String[20]`

Comment: I guessed I missed to take aa as user input. Please take it as user input, ex: aa = s.nextInt().

Comment: Well... you forgot to include the most important part of your code causing the problem. Because you used the Scanner#nextInt() method, when the ENTER key is hit on entry the newline character is not consumed and scanner applies it on the first nextLine() method it encounters which then appears to skip it. Just add this: `s.nextLine();` directly after the `nextInt()` call and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not giving a valid integer when constructing the String array. Instead of `aa`, you should have a number. Since you ask for 20 names, then you should declare an array of size 20.

Edit: Assuming `aa` is user input, you just need to consume the next line after reading. Note that this also happens when using nextDouble with the scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names would you like to enter?");
    int aa = s.nextInt();
    //must include since nextInt leaves the new line
    s.nextLine();
    String[] array = new String[aa];
    System.out.println("Please enter " + aa + " names to sort");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = s.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(array[0]);

}
```

Also, please note that the array will not sort itself! You'll have to implement that later.